# jquery/css calendar bug

Tags: javascript, css, calendar

I have a jquery calendar inside a jquery accordion, the problem is that the calendar is not 100% visible, but when i switch the month and then come to the actual month  everything it's ok.
check out this link to see what I'm talking about [here](http://www.outboxvision.com/accordion)

Comment: link does not work -- 404 error

Comment: http://www.outboxvision.com/accordion/

Comment: sorry, now the link it's working, any help ?

Comment: Looks fine to me.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding the problem, but if I expand the first section I see the full calendar.

Comment: It doesn't look fine, for example click on next month and then come back to the previous month and you will see the difference

Comment: Er, Cross Domain Policy Violation, anyone? I get this error message in the console 74 times on page load. Might or might not be related:  *Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.outboxvision.com/accordion/ from frame with URL http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&ie=UTF8&ll=38.975296,1.416955&spn=0,0&t=h&iwloc=0004a498bffd73c66ce14&msid=214022389727477218012.0004a4987d5ed1463cc2d&output=embed. Domains, protocols and ports must match.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that jQuery booking calendar, but from the looks of things the height on *div.DOP_FrontendBookingCalendar_Container* is being set to 400px inline (probably rendered by the jQuery plugin).

The UI adjusts the parent container to 400px tall, but the children don't adjust the first time loading the page. Once you click to the next month it seems to recognize the parent's height and adjust accordingly.

Might be as simple as setting the height of that element to 500px (or whatever is appropriate) to get the child elements to squeeze in the first time through.